# C++ std:string comparation codification problems

Tags: c++, string, encoding, std, utf

I have a problem with a std::string comparation with codification I think. The problem is that I hate to compare a a string that is received and I dont know how kind of codification it has with a spanish string with unusal characters. I cant change s_area.m_s_area_text so I need to set s2 string with a identical value and i dont know how to do it in a generic way for other chases.

```
std::string s2= "Versión de sistema";  
std::cout << s_area.m_s_area_text << std::endl;

for (const char* p = s2.c_str(); *p; ++p)
{
   printf("%02x", *p);
}
printf("\n");


for (const char* p = s_area.m_s_area_text.c_str(); *p; ++p)
{
   printf("%02x", *p);
}
printf("\n");
```

And the result of the execution is:

```
Versi├│n de sistema
5665727369fffffff36e2064652073697374656d61
5665727369ffffffc3ffffffb36e2064652073697374656d61
```

Obviously, as the 2 strings has not the same bytes values, all the compare method fails: strncmp, std::string ==, std:sstring.comapre etc.

Any idea of how to do that witho touching s_area.m_s_area_text string?

Comment: you dont compare the string in the code, right?

Comment: Looks like you need a comparison function that doesn't compare bytes, but something else. You can either write such a function or alternatively convert both strings into a canonical representation so the byte-comparison functions are enough. That depends on what bytes you wish to ignore.

Comment: I have skipped the compare function... all of them return false. I need to compare the whole string without skkiping any character.

Comment: @nwp I totally ignorant in this field, but how to determine which encoding is using by user to convert it ?

Comment: But that's what the comparison functions already did. They compared without skipping anything and told you that the bytes are different, which is correct. But since you are not happy with that you seem to want to skip some of the bytes to make `5665727369fffffff36e2064652073697374656d61` and `5665727369ffffffc3ffffffb36e2064652073697374656d61` compare equal, even though they are not.

Comment: @Garf365 Generally you just have to know based on the API. Sometimes people use [markers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) that you can use to guess the encoding, but there is no general way to figure out the encoding of any string based only on its content.

Comment: I need to convert my s2 string with the same codification than the source and then compare theses 2 strings, comparing the whole string including secial chars.

Comment: I think when you say "codification" you mean "encoding" and the question is "how do I compare strings for equality when they have different encoding". The answer is probably to convert both strings to the same encoding and possibly normalize them and then compare them by byte value.

Comment: If you can provide more information a solution might be possible. For instance are you taking user input with a known encoding and comparing it to data in a database or data file of known encoding and the problem is actually that the two are different encodings but both known (or at least can be figured out before hand).

Answer (score 0):

In general it is impossible to guess the encoding of a string by inspecting its raw bytes. The exception to this rule is when a byte order mark (BOM) is present at the start of the byte stream. The BOM will tell you which unicode encoding the bytes are and the endianness.

As an aside, if at some point in the future you decide you need a canonical string encoding (as some have pointed out in the comments that it would be a good idea). There are strong arguments in favour of UTF-8 as the best choice for C++. See [UTF-8 everywhere](http://utf8everywhere.org/) for further information on this.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, two compare two string correctly you at least need to know their encoding. In your example `s_area.m_s_area_text` is happened to be encoded with UTF-8 while for `s2` ISO/IEC 8859-1 (Latin-1) is used.

If you are sure that `s_area.m_s_area_text` will always be encoded in UTF-8, you can try to make `s2` use the same encoding and then just compare them. One way of defining a UTF-8 encoded string is escaping every character that is not in basic character set with `\u`.

```
std::string s2 = u8"Versi\u00F3n de sistema";
...
if (s_area.m_s_area_text == s2)
...
```

It should also be possible to do it without escaping the characters by setting an appropriate encoding for the source file and specifying the encoding to the compiler.

As @nwp mentioned, you may also want to normalise the strings before comparing. Otherwise, two strings that look the same may have different Unicode representation and that will cause your comparison to yield a false negative result.
For example, "Versión de sistema" will not be equal to "Versión de sistema".